# Finding a specific module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I want to think of a module $M$ over a commutative ring with identity $R$ such that $M \oplus N = R^3 $ while $N$ is isomorphic to $M$. Are there some interesting examples which satisfies this condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible.

Since $M \oplus N = R^3$, both $M,N$ are projective modules, hence locally free. Choose a prime ideal $\mathfrak p \subset R$. Then, localizing, we get $M_{\mathfrak p} \oplus N_{\mathfrak p} \simeq R_{\mathfrak p}^n \oplus R_{\mathfrak p}^m = R_{\mathfrak p}^3$.

But $R$ is commutative, so by tensoring with $R/\mathfrak m$ we find that $n+m=3$. Hence they cannot be equal and so no such $M,N$ can exists.

Comment: Note that if you drop the commutativity assumption, then it becomes possible (for instance by taking $R$ to be the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices over a field).

Comment: Well, it *is* possible in case when $R$ is a zero ring (if you consider it a ring with identity). Of course, this hardly qualifies as an interesting example. ;-)

Comment: Tensoring by $R/m$? The rank of free modules still exists.

Comment: @user26857 Just to be sure! This is the way one shows that the rank of free modules over a commutative ring is well-defined anyways.